# Unable to run node app.js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I am learning node.js and I am trying to run the app.js file using the command `node app.js` but the bash returns nothing (no errors either). Here are the steps I followed:

`$ brew install node`

`$ sudo npm install -g express`

`$ sudo npm install -g express-generator`

after i get into a new folder I created I run

`$ express testsite --hogan -c less`

`$ cd testsite && npm install`

Finally

`$ node app.js` // returns no errors but nothing back except new command line...

Any help on this would be great.

Thanks!

Comment: Really? I get an error that points me to: http://goo.gl/YnK8p0

Comment: And after I fix that error (commenting out less, who needs that?!), I run it with node app.js and it works fine. `Express server listening on port 3001`. The command `http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function(){});` should not end the process - is that present?

Comment: Ok I will remove that and try again i am using this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ndKRjmA6WNA).

Comment: Still not working for me...

Comment: `node -v` gives you what exactly?

Comment: You should use `node start`

Answer (score 92, accepted):

try `npm start` from **testsite** directory.

look at the **package.json**

```
scripts : { start : node bin/www }
```

So you must execute the **www** under the **bin** directory.

So instead of `node app.js` use `node bin/www`

Comment: Can someone explain why it works and what is the purpose of it?

Comment: great answer. npm start did all the work for me. cheers @user626818

Comment: what if i don't have a bin/www dir

Comment: Use 'yarn start' if you use yarn.

Comment: It does not working for me. It gives an error below,

Error: Cannot find module 'I:\Property inspection\Video-Call-App-NodeJS\src\bin\www'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:889:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}

Answer (score 14):

Try running nodejs app.js instead of node app.js

Comment: Actually, node command is part of node-legacy package that you can download using apt...

Comment: @Pikamander2 nodejs is used on ubuntu instead of node, can't remember why or if it's the same on other linux flavours.

Answer (score 13):

You have to add this code to **app.js** file, this will tell express to listen on port 3000 and display a log message

```
 app.listen(3000, function () {
console.log("Express server listening on port 3000");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

After running...

```
express testsite --hogan -c less
```

I get the following message:

```
install dependencies:
  $ cd testsite && npm install

run the app:
  $ DEBUG=test ./bin/www
```

`node app.js` did not work for me either, but `./bin/www` does.

FYI `npm start` also works for me. This basically runs `./bin/www`.

EDIT: Was curious why node.app doesn't work, because I followed the same video guide. In the comments, someone said node changed their app start process since video was made.

Answer (score 2):

the answer to this problem is simple ......
first save your file .... by command CMD + S

and then type - node app.js in terminal

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem, I found that the problem was in a library called bcrypt,once i removed that library everything worked fine.
So try to comment out the libraries you are using in app.js one by one and you will get to know which one is causing problem

Answer (score 0):

**Unable to run node app.js file**

I came to this question in a very basic scenario. I was missing to mention an end point (response) and the browser was forever loading.

I fixed it with providing a response.

```
app.use ((req, res, next) => {
res.send('Hello World');
});
```

Answer (score -2):

Add app.listen(3000); to your app.js file.